How to use git-clone with code-server, using ssh key and gitlab
I'm using code-server and its git-clone module.
I've configured it this way in main.tf :
module "git-clone" {
  source   = "registry.coder.com/modules/git-clone/coder"
  version  = "1.0.14"
  agent_id = coder_agent.main.id
  url      = "ssh://git@git.example.com/xxxx.git"
  git_providers = {
    "https://example.com/" = {
      provider = "gitlab"
    }
  }
}

I've also added coder's ssh key to my gitlab account (on a private instance of gitlab).
But, when creating a workspace, I get the following message :
Encountered an error running "coder gitssh"
exit status 255
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I've tried executing git clone with the same link a terminal inside a workspace and it works. I don't understand why it doesn't work here.
